# How to skip an argument using <functional> in C++11/98

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

Say I have a function:

```
void function() {
    cout << "Hello!" << endl;
}
```

And I have an algorithm that calls a function and passes it two arguments:

```
template <class F>
void my_algorithm(F f) {
    // ...
    f(x, y);
    // ...
}
```

How can I pass `function` to `my_algorithm` by manipulating the function or function object, without manually creating a wrapper? For reference, the wrapper I don't want to create would look like this:

```
void functionSkipArgs(A a, B b) {
    function();
}
```

In other words, I'd like to find the function or series of functions that correspond to `some_operations` in the following code:

```
my_algorithm(some_operations(&function));
```

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work: http://ideone.com/6DgbA6

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;


void func() {
    cout << "Hello!" << endl;
}

template<class F>
void my_algorithm(F f) {
    int x = 100;
    int y = 200;

    f(x, y);
}


int main() {

    my_algorithm(std::bind(func));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He marked it c++11, in which lambada are usually preferred to bind, and more readable.

Comment: True indeed, but I wasn't thinking about a lambda solution which would arguably be better. My thinking as he just didn't want to "wrap" it in anything at all. No doubt there are better solutions out there and lambda is one of them.

Comment: Bind creates a function wrapper.

Comment: I'll upvote you. Same code, different thought process.

Comment: Good question though.

Comment: Wow, `std::bind` has a lot of uses. Any idea if this is possible to do in C++98, where there is no `std::bind`?

Comment: @AndresRiofrio, `boost::bind`

Comment: @AndresRiofrio if you don't want c++11 answers, then don't tag your question c++11

Comment: @RussellGreene I thought it was unlikely to be doable in C++98 without Boost, so C++11 answers are fine. I forgot to tag it also with C++98 at first, even though it's in the title. :)

Comment: I would also prefer bind to a lambda in such a simple forwarding case.

Answer (score 3):

In c++11, which your question is tagged, Use a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).
Here's the code:

```
my_algorithm([](A, B) 
{ 
    return function();
});
```

What a lambda does for you is it creates that wrapper for your.

If you want for that to be generic (templated) and you have c++14, then your can use auto:

```
my_algorithm([](auto, auto) 
{ 
    return function();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `std::function` and lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<functional>

void function() {
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}

template <typename F>
void my_algorithm(F f) {    
    int x=0;
    int y=10;
    f(x, y);    
}

int main()
{  
    std::function<void(int,int)> fun= [](int x, int y){  function();};        
    my_algorithm(fun);
}
```

Comment: This adds the extra complexity of std::function